# What is the practical purpose of instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby rails, and I'm struggling to understand what the purpose of instance variables are.

What is the point of making a variable into an instance variable?

Basically why would I do this:

```
class User
   def initialize(var1)
     @name = var1
   end
end
```

over this:

```
class User
   def initialize(var1)
     name = var1
   end
end
```

And in what types of situations would I want to use an instance variable over just a regular variable?

Comment: check this http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html

Comment: In your second example, you wouldn't be able to access name from another method. That is all  instance variables do, maintain object's state.

Comment: Just like Sergio said, the `name` local variable is immediately thrown away when Ruby interpreter exits `initialize` method, therefore this version of `initialize` does nothing.

Comment: Gotcha, so the point of instance variables is to have them persist beyond the method they are defined in?

Comment: Sort of, but it 'is' possible to implicitly extend the 'lifespan' of local variable as well, using closures. And the scope of instance variable is defined by the instance. I guess you simply need to read about variables scoping in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The practical use for this is that if you need a variable to persist across function calls, make it an instance variable.

after you define the instance variable, you can call the value of this on another function and you will have the value.

In general an instance variable is local and persisted inside an instance of an object, whereas a local variable is only local and persisted inside a function/object/block scope.

in your example if you have another method on your user class, you can use the value of @name on that other method, but coulnd't use var1 outside of initialize method.

```
class User
   def initialize(var1)
     @name = var1
   end

   def greetings
     "hello #{@name}"
   end    
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class People
  def age
    @age
  end

  def age= age
    @age = age
  end
end

def show people
  age = people.age || '22'
  p "Hello, my age is #{age}"
end

people = People.new
show people
=> 'Hello, my age is 22'
age
=> NameError: undefined local variable or method 'age' for main:Object
user.age = 21
greet people
=> 'Hello, my age is 21'
@age
=> nil
```

Notice that both variable types are local to a specific context though. @age is defined within the people instance, so when you call people.age you are calling the age function in the age instance, in which @age is defined. age is only defined in the show function, so when you call  p "Hello, my age is #{age}" you are able to get a value for age because you are within the scope in which it is defined.

Comment: What is `user`?

Answer (score -2):

Because your instance variable will be accessible to your view code, including within forms and passing data to paths. That's probably the most common, practical use case for them. In your example, I could do the following:

```
<p>User: <%= "#{@name}" %></p>
```

And, instead of seeing "@name" in my corresponding paragraph in the rendered H.T.M.L, you'd see the value of that instance variable - whereas the inverse:

```
<p>User: <%= "#{name}" %></p>
```

...will probably result in an ActionView error, since "name" is undefined, according to it.

Comment: The linkage between controller and view instance variables is a little bit artificial and doesn't even nearly exhaust the topic of instance variables usage. You seem to think of it the way "rails programmers" tend to do, but it isn't correct in any way.